# The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns one select one into

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a pretty straightforward error, but I can't figure out why I am getting it. I have one column selected in my declare (TABLE_NAME) and am fetching into one variable (@cTableName). What gives?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateNumbers_ArchiveDB]
(
 @accountNumber varchar(50),
 @padding varchar(50),
 @proc_dateStart datetime,
 @proc_dateEnd datetime
 )
 AS

 DECLARE @cTableName varchar(50)

    DECLARE CursorYearlyTables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'Archive[12]%' and len(TABLE_NAME) = 14
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

-- =============================================
-- Open the cursor and iterate over the monthlies
-- =============================================
OPEN CursorYearlyTables 
fetch next from CursorYearlyTables into @cTableName
while (@@fetch_status <> -1)

 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 

declare @q varchar(1000);

set @q = 'Update' + @cTableName +
         'SET LogicalAccount = @padding + @accountNumber' +
         'WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN CAST(@proc_dateStart AS DATE) AND CAST(@proc_dateEnd AS DATE)'
exec(@q)

fetch next from CursorYearlyTables into @cTableName

END

close CursorYearlyTables;
DEALLOCATE CursorYearlyTables;
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Try declairing `@q` at the beginning, not in the loop. what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. I moved the @q declaration to the beginning, same error.

Comment: Sorry for minor commnets, but you have no spaces between hard coded parts and variables. it should be `UPDATE<space>` + @cTableName. Also if you are hard coding variable in, you need to assing values inside that code too. Variale values are not passed from your session/batch into context where d-sql is executed.

Comment: Try PRINTing out the `@q` variable and see what SQL you are attempting to run.

Comment: Both good points... printing the variable would make it more obvious that you are indeed missing required spaces. `UPDATEATableSet LogicalAccount..` is definitely invalid SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try it with these lines in the cursor

```
declare @q nvarchar(max);

set @q = 'Update ' + @cTableName +
         'SET LogicalAccount = '+@padding + @accountNumber +
         'WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateStart)+''' AS DATE) AND CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateEnd)+''' AS DATE)'

exec sp_executesql @q
```

to account for SQL_Injection DavidG commented:

```
declare 
    @q nvarchar(max) = 'update '+@cTableName+' SET LogicalAccount = @a where ProcessDate BETWEEN CAST(@b AS DATE) AND CAST(@c AS DATE))',
    @param1 nvarchar(100) = @padding+ @accountNumber,
    @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500) = N'@a varchar(100), @b datetime, @c datetime'

exec sp_executesql @q, @ParamDefinition,@a = @param1,@b = @proc_dateStart, @cTableName = @proc_dateEnd
```

Comment: Missing some single quotes around the `@padding` and `@accountNumber` concatenation. Also this leaves the OP open to SQL injection.

Comment: Same error. I can't figure out why this is being so stubborn.

Comment: I see from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576860/what-is-wrong-with-my-dynamic-sql-query-using-a-char-data-type that you got this working by adding the required space after the update statement and before the set (which this answer does not suggest)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `CONVERT` function

```
  CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(108),@proc_dateStart)+''' AS DATE) AND CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(108),@proc_dateEnd)+''' AS DATE)'
```

Comment: AdiT, you really don't need to format your entire answer as code: I know I've commented a few times on your answers, and I've seen others do the same, but I'm not sure you've realized the issue.  `Regular text does not need to be formatted as code!!!`