# What is wrong with my dynamic SQL Query? Using a char data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This query will not work if we include the AND HostApplication clause.

Parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateNumbers_ArchiveDB]
(
   @accountNumber varchar(50),
   @accountType char(4),
   @padding varchar(50),
   @proc_dateStart datetime,
   @proc_dateEnd datetime
)
```

Here is the dynamic SQL:

```
set @q = 'Update ' + @cTableName +
     ' SET LogicalAccount = '+ @padding + @accountNumber +
     ' WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateStart)+''' AS DATE) AND CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateEnd)+''' AS DATE)' +
     ' AND HostApplication =' + '''+ @accountType +'''
```

Here is my exec statement:

```
exec updateNumbers_ArchiveDB @accountNumber = N'1020',
                             @accountType = N'd',
                             @padding = N'123',
                             @proc_dateStart = '2014-01-30',
                             @proc_dateEnd = '2014-01-31'
```

If I remove a single quote around `@accounttype`: `(''+@accounttype +'')` I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'd'.

With 3 quotes it works runs without error, but no updates are made.

With 1 quote `(('+@accounttype +'))` I get:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@accountType".

I realize there is an art to using quotes in dynamic SQL, but I have not found any resources on using the char data type in dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ ''''+ @accountType +''''
```

Should fix it

Comment: Lol, of course it just needed another single quote. I am not good at Dynamic SQL, thank you!

Comment: not a problem, don't forget to mark as answered. thanks